# Gremlin: how to overcome property null problem and write a query which updates all properties of a certain vertex?

Tags: gremlin

I need to write a single Gremlin query that can set the new property values of a vertex. All the property names are known in advance (in this example: Type, Country, Status). Some of the property values can be null - and I don't know which ones in advance. The query should work for all cases. For example, let's say I currently have this query:

```
g.V(123).
property('Type',Type).
property('Country',Country).
property('Status',Status)
```

This query works fine if all the parameter (Type, Country, Status) values are non-null. If, say, Country is null, I get an error:

`The AddPropertyStep does not have a provided value: AddPropertyStep({key=[Country]})`

In such case I would need to use a different query to drop the property (by the way, is there a better way for dropping a property?):

```
g.V(123).
property('Type',Type).
property('Status',Status).
properties('Country').drop()
```

Is it possible to write a universal query that can handle both null and non-null values? I cannot use console or programming, just a single Gremlin query to be executed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TinkerPop doesn't allow `null` values in properties (though you might find some graph databases allowing different semantics there, I suppose), so you should validate your data up front to ensure that it has some meaningful "empty value" as opposed to a `null`. If you can't do that for some reason, I guess you could use `choose()` step to "check for null":

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').valueMap()
==>[name:[marko],age:[29]]
gremlin> age = null
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').choose(constant(age).count().is(0), properties('age').drop(),property('age',age))
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').valueMap()
==>[name:[marko]]
gremlin> age = 30
==>30
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').choose(constant(age).count().is(0), properties('age').drop(),property('age',age))
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').valueMap()
==>[name:[marko],age:[30]]
```

The check for "is null" is basically just: `constant(age).count().is(0)`, which leans on the Gremlin's semantics for `null` values in a stream being empty and giving a `count()` of zero. It works, but it makes your Gremlin a little less readable. That might be a nice [DSL step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-java-dsl) to add if you have to write that a lot.

Comment: This is great, thank you very much! The query would then look something like this. It seems to work fine. Could it be simplified?
`g.V(123).choose(constant(Type).count().is(0), optional(properties('Type').drop()), property('Type',Type)).choose(constant(Status).count().is(0)......`

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by "simplified" given your example, though you're probably right to use `optional()` so that you can chain more steps on the end as `drop()` behaves like a filter step and kills all traversers. it might be more readable to go with `sideEffect()` instead of `optional()` though...at least that would be my preference.